# Search live through json to see if given string is in the array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, search

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var names = ["nick", "nicky", "nickyy", "nick23", "nickfe09", "nickf9", "jim1", "jimbo2"];

    $.each(names, function (index, value) {
        $('<span>').html(value + '<br>').appendTo('#div');
    });

    $('#input').change(function (event) {
        $('#div > span:contains("' + $('#input').val() + '")').css('background', 'red');
    });
});
```

```
<div id="div"></div>
<input type="text" id="input">
```

Hello again stackoverflow!

I have a string with usernames. I want to display them in a table (or in this example, just a list) and then display only like 10 of them (There are going to be ~200 names in the list eventually). When the user inputs something in the input field, for example `nic`, I want it to filter the rest and display the 10 best matching usernames.

I've tried the setup above but this didn't work. Could you guys help me?

Greetings

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4wZ2L/5/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [See this working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/4wZ2L/8/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var names = ["nick", "nicky", "nickyy", "nick23", "nickfe09", "nickf9", "jim1", "jimbo2"];
    $.each(names, function (index, value) {
        $('<span>').html(value + '<br>').appendTo('#div');
    });
    $('#input').on("change keyup", function (event) {
        $('#div > span').css('background','');
        $('#div > span:contains("' + $(this).val() + '")').css('background', 'red');
    });
});
```

All I did was the following:

1. Make it so `#input` responds to the `keyup` event in addition to `change`.
2. Clear all of the `spans` of their formatting before determining which ones match.
3. In the line where you actually change the content, I changed `input.val` to `$(this).val()`. The variable `input` was undefined.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This did the job. Thanks!